# Need to find age of actor who was the oldest at a release of movie, in 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have two tables with multiple relations

Relevant info from tables

Person:

```
Id |   Name |    Birthyear
```

Movie:

```
ID |    Name |    Releaseyear
```

Movie_Actor:

```
MovieID |    ActorID
```

The query, I tried :

```
SELECT movie.name AS Movie, person.name, movie.releaseyear - person.birthyear AS Age
FROM movie_actor
INNER JOIN movie
ON movie.id = movie_actor.movieid
INNER JOIN person
ON person.id = movie_actor.actorID
```

This shows me name of movie and actor, aswell as the age of the actor in the year the movie was released. However i need it only to show 1 result, the actor who was the oldest at the release of a movie he/she played in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use limit 1

```
SELECT 
     movie.name AS Movie, 
     person.name, 
     movie.releaseyear - person.birthyear AS Age
FROM movie_actor 
INNER JOIN movie ON movie.id = movie_actor.movieid 
INNER JOIN person ON person.id = movie_actor.actorID
order by age desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I was trying all kinds of variations of Group by and WHERE, franticly googling how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use aggregation function MAX to limit and get the highest age difference as well,

```
SELECT 
     movie.name AS Movie, 
     person.name, 
     MAX(movie.releaseyear - person.birthyear) AS Age
FROM movie_actor 
INNER JOIN movie ON movie.id = movie_actor.movieid 
INNER JOIN person ON person.id = movie_actor.actorID
group by Movie,person.name
```